# Timer with a reset

Tags: java

Is there an efficient way to implement a countdown timer with a reset function in Java?

I'm sending events to a server as they occur. If no event happens for a while, I need to send a heartbeat signal so the server knows we're still alive. An event must get sent no less frequently than every 200 milliseconds.

Ideally, I'd have a countdown timer that I'd set to 200 ms. Every time an event occurs I'd reset the timer back to 200 ms. If the timer times out it would send a heartbeat and reset itself.

I don't want to tie up a thread for each timer because I may need several of them. I don't want use a Timer + TimerTask, because each reset would require creating a new TimerTask and adding it to a queue. Under heavy load I may have to fire several thousand events per second and don't want to create a TimerTask for each one.

The best scheme I've come up with is to use a `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(...);` and fire it every 10 or 20 milliseconds. I could check the countdown value every tick and reset it as necessary. This doesn't feel very efficient, though, and won't give me a good timer resolution.

Is there a better way?

Comment: the Timer object can run only Task at a time, and it will get delayed when previous task takes more time doing the job

Answer (score 2):

You can roll your own resettable timer with [`Object.wait(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) and [`Object.notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()).

```
public abstract class ResettableTimer implements Runnable {

    private Object lock = new Object();
    private long timeout_ms;
    private long last;

    public ResettableTimer(long timeout_ms) {
        this.timeout_ms = timeout_ms;
    }

    public void reset() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            last = System.currentTimeMillis();
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                for (;;) {
                    lock.wait(timeout_ms);
                    long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - last;
                    if (delta >= timeout_ms) {
                        timeout();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    protected abstract void timeout();
}
```

Create a subclass, override `timeout()` to send your heartbeat message.  Every time a message is sent, call the `ResettableTimer#reset()` method to reset the heartbeat timer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is really elegant, thanks. It does have the downside of tying up a thread, but it's otherwise efficient. I wonder how Object.wait() is implemented under the covers, and if it's doing some processing during a timer tick just as I suggested with the .scheduleAtFixedRate() method?

Comment: Re-reading your question, I see you didn't want one thread per timer.  You want more than one resettable heartbeat timer?  Interesting.  If so, you could reimplement the `run()` loop to determine which timer would next expire (perhaps using a `PriorityQueue`) and `lock.wait(next_expiry_ms)`.  Each timer would, of course, need its own `Runnable` to execute on `timeout()`.  So you'd split this into multiple `ResettableTimer` objects and one `ResettableTimer.Manager`.  A little more work, but should result in a clean, reusable utility class.

Answer (score 1):

Using an ExecutorService makes sense. Goetz, et al., deem it an improvement over a util.Timer in *Java Concurrency in Practice*.

I'd consider something like the following:

- have a volatile variable that holds the *lastEventTime* of the last event
- set a non-repeating TimerTask that executes at *lastEventTime* + 200 ms

When the TimerTask occurs, if the *lastEventTime* is > 200 ms in the past, send your ping and update the *lastEventTime* variable to the present, then create and set a new TimerTask to check again at the new *lastEventTime* + 200 (which will be 200 ms in the future).

If an event occurred less than 200 ms in the past (for example say 150 ms in the past) when the TimerTask checks in, set the next TimerTask to check in again at the current *lastEventTime* + 200 (50 ms into the future, in the example case).